# Excel Assistance with VBA button that adds new rows with drop downs and formula

Tags: excel, vba, row, formula, new-operator

I have added a button to add new rows that semi-works and needs some help refining it or open to new suggestions.

So when the button is pressed, a pop-up box is prompted to input desired number of blanks rows, starting from row 5. This works and the drop boxes are there, however, any formula is cleared.

I have this VBA

```
Sub AddRows()

Dim x As Integer

x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")

'Selecting range to insert new cells
Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(x + 4, 1)).EntireRow.Insert

'Copys current cell A6 and past in the new cells
Cells(x + 5, 1).Copy Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(x + 4, 1))

'if you want the cells to be blank but still have the drop down options
Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(x + 4, 1)).ClearContents

End Sub
```

I have formula in columns I,J,K,L,Q,R,V,W,X. Is there a way the new row can keep the formula?

I think it would leave the row blank if I cleared the non-formula cells only. A - H, M - P, S, T, U, Y, Z

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try clearing only the non-formula cells?  You have the syntax, which just needs a slight adjustment for each column to be cleared.

Comment: add `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to whatever range you want to keep the formulas.  You will want to add an Error Handler because if there are no vaules in any of the cells Excel will throw an error at you.

Comment: Cells(x + 5, 1).Copy, you need to extend this, this is only copying 1 cell.

Comment: If I clear the non-formula cells with my rows as they are they become blank, which I want. Do you know how I could adjust this to clear the range I am after?

Comment: Ah ok! how would I extend (x + 5, 1) to copy a bigger range? Apologies, new to VBA codes.